# How to calculate where the 2nd and 3rd dots go in order to create a ring using dots?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, geometry

Suppose you have a circle that is 1 cm in radius. Now you add many more.

How do you align these so that you can create a big ring made up of these circles?

how do you calculate where the second circle should be placed, the third one, etc.?

I will use this platform to test the answer.

http://jsfiddle.net/7pqvf6mL/

I have a 5 pixel radius dot in a 200x200px platform. Lets assume this dot represents the top of the
ring that is to be created.

Where should the next dot be placed? And all the other dots so that I can create a perfect ring with these dots?

```
     .
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25463962/css-how-to-find-the-formula-to-create-a-ring-using-dots-in-a-square-box

Answer (score 1):

Trig is super-handy when doing this kind of work

You need to use the parametric equation for a circle:

```
x = cx + r * cos(a)
y = cy + r * sin(a)
```

`r` is the radius of the circle, `cx` and `cy` is the center of the circle, and `a` is the angle the point is to reside on from 0 to 2PI radians.

So what you need to do is divide 2PI (number of radians in a circle) by the number of elements you want evenly spaced around the circle. Say you want 10 elements positioned on a circle's circumference:

```
2PI/10 = 0.628
```

`0.628` is the incremented angle that you want to place the element at. For each element, since you need to move to the next increment, you will multiply by the element's index position. So, for the first element, `a = (0.628 * 1)`, the second will be `a = (0.628 * 2)` and so on.

In pseudocode:

```
circleRadius = 10;
circleX = 0;
circleY = 0;
numberOfElements = 10;
a = ((2*PI)/numberOfElements);
for i = 1; i <= numberOfElements; i++:
  x = circleX + circleRadius * cos(a*i);
  y = circleY + circleRadius * sin(a*i);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to consider the problem that'll make the solution much clearer.

Let's say you've already got a bunch of these dots set up like that. What does it look like if we zoom in on a few of them?

[image: Three circles arranged along the perimeter of a much larger circle]

What's important about this diagram is that:

- The center of each dot is exactly on the edge of the larger circle.
- More importantly, the radius of each dot nearly coincides with the edge of the larger circle that's defining them.

As long as the dots are *much* smaller than the larger circle, we can approximate the larger circle as a series of line segments running between the centers and points of contact of each dot. Thus, the circumference of the larger circle is nearly equal to the product of the diameter of each dot and the number of dots.

Since the circumference of a circle is given by `2πr` and the diameter of a dot is `2r`, it will be true that:

```
2 π Rbig = 2 N Rsmall
```

or, after some simple algebraic transformations:

```
N = π * Rbig / Rsmall
```

where `Rbig` is the radius of the larger circle, `Rsmall` is the radius of a dot, and `N` is the number of dots.

Note that, since N must be an integer, there are some constraints on the exact values of `Rbig` and `Rsmall` if you want the dots to line up perfectly. For instance, with your given values of `Rbig` = 100px and `Rsmall` = 5px, we get `N = 62.83`. Since you can't have a non-integer number of circles, it will be necessary to fudge the sizes a bit (or round N up and accept some overlap) until you get a clean value.

Now that we know how many dots are needed, we can use the parametric equation of a circle (`x = cos(θ), y = sin(θ)`) to draw the circle:

```
var Rbig = 95;
var Rsmall = 5;

var N = Math.ceil(Math.PI * Rbig / Rsmall);
var theta = 0;

var target = document.getElementById("a");

for (var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    theta += 2 * Math.PI / N;
    var x = Rbig + Rbig * Math.cos(theta);
    var y = Rbig + Rbig * Math.sin(theta);

    var dot = document.createElement("div");
    dot.setAttribute("class", "c");
    dot.style.left = x + "px";
    dot.style.top = y + "px";
    target.appendChild(dot);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7pqvf6mL/10/

[image: And here's the results!]

Note that I had to adjust the definition of the `.c` class slightly to make this work — as written, it had a 2.5 px radius, not 5 px. I also had to set `Rbig` to 95, not 100, as the 5 px radius of each dot increased the radius of the overall circle!